# How to upload Video in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image and video but not able to upload video.
Its working fine for image upload, but not able to upload video.

**for upload file**

```
if ([localReachability isReachable]) {

    AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];

    AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *task, NSError *error) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MLog(@"file Upload Completion handler ");
        if (!error) {
          MLog(@"file is uploaded successfully ");
          [self fileUploadDidFinish];
        }
        else {
          MLog(@"Image is failed to upload");
          MLog(@"Error ::: %@",error);
          [self fileUploadDidFail];
        }
      });
    };

    [[transferUtility uploadData:fileToUpload bucket:S3_BUCKET key:uploadPath contentType:@"image/jpg" expression:nil completionHander:completionHandler] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

      if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result;
        [uploadTask  cancel];
      }

      if (task.result) {
        AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *uploadTask = task.result;
        MLog(@"uploadTask result :: %@",uploadTask);
      }
      return nil;
    }];
  }
```

Please update me where I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you post the error log with the question?

Comment: Perhaps your ContentType is the issue?

Comment: For tips on how to ask a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, for us to help please let us know what the actual error is you are getting.  As Zeretil noticed, if this is the same code you are using to upload videos then your ContentType is specifying that it is a jpeg file, not a video file.